# Mijoshop "Add To Cart" with custom options

Tags: php, joomla

I am working with Joomla and Mijoshop currently but they do not meet my needs as I also am having to integrate these with jCalPro. The idea is that users can create events on jCalPro, and members can sign up for them.

The problem is figuring out how to integrate jCalPro into MijoShop so that members can pay for the event and have it tracked properly in the orders tables when purchased. We have products in Mijoshop for the Event Types with prices and details. These products roughly correlate to our jCalPro Events. I need to be able to put an item into the Mijoshop shopping cart that will add the product (event), but also populate an option that contains the jCalPro Event ID so i can track it. Once I have this I can write custom pages to pull reporting data and the like. I am using custom PHP I have written and just adding them to the Joomla application.

I know MijoShop has an "addToShoppingCart" function as I can see it in the file:

```
components/com_mijoshop/assets/js/product.js
```

The issue is that I do not know how to load the MijoShop class into the page so I can use the function.  Does it load by default when I include the page in the in the Joomla application. I am using the following code which works fine for most Joomla functions:

```
// Joomla session enable
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
// define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'JPATH_BASE', '/my/path/' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe  = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user       = JFactory::getUser();
$config     =& JFactory::getConfig();
$session    =& JFactory::getSession();
```

As you can see I have more hurdles to overcome as I first need access to this function, and then I need it to populate a custom product option when I use it.

Any help would be appreciated as I have found little documentation about MijoShop and even less on how to integrate it with the likes of jCalPro.

Comment: if i knew how to change the bounty to 1000 i would ... :) ... need this one solved asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have found a solution that equates to roughly the following:

```
try {
    // Now we add the product to the user's shopping cart
    // First we'll get the product ID of the event in question
    // My JCalPro has a custom field called "Event type" that I have manually populated with the select
    // Mijoshop product ID's and thier associated "Model" into. The easiest way I could see to make them line up.
    // the event ID used here was provided to my script prior to this query
    $queryText = "SELECT * FROM jcalpro_events WHERE id = '".$eventID."'";
    $db->setQuery($queryText);
    $eventInfo = $db->loadAssoc();
    $eventData = json_decode($eventInfo['params']);
    $product_id = $eventData->Event;
    // Get the product info, including the currently defined option
    // for my purposes the product only has one option in mijoshop_product_option called "eventid"
    // which is a blank text field that is not required.
    $queryText = "
        SELECT p.*, po.product_option_id 
        FROM mijoshop_product p
        LEFT JOIN mijoshop_product_option po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
        WHERE p.product_id = '".$product_id."'";
    $db->setQuery($queryText);
    $productInfo = $db->loadAssoc();
    // $userInfo is a previous query where i grabbed the user's details
    // including Joomla User ID, Mijoshop User ID, email, etc
    $mUID = $userInfo['mUID']; // get mijoshop user ID for use
    $jUID = $userInfo['jUID']; // get Joomla user ID for use
    // First we have to log out the user in question so thier shopping cart will remain once we update it.
    // If we don't do this, the shopping cart will be overwritten any time they reload thier page.
    if ($mainframe->logout($jUID)) {
        // Replace the user's shopping cart to have the event's product in MijoShop
        $quantity = 1;                                                     // Default value for this project
        $option = array($productInfo['product_option_id'] => $eventID);    // Define array with option ID and value
        $serOption = serialize($option);                                   // Serialize the options
        $product_key = (int)$product_id . ':' . base64_encode($serOption); // Generate the Product info for the Cart
        $products = array($product_key => $quantity);                      // Put the products into an array, product type => quantity
        $serProducts = serialize($products);                               // Serialize that array for the cart
        // Now we can insert the product into the shopping cart
        $queryText = "UPDATE mijoshop_customer SET cart = '".$serProducts."' WHERE customer_id = '".$mUID."'";
        $db->setQuery($queryText);
        $db->execute();
        if ($debug) {echo "Step 8 - Placed the product in the ueser's Mijoshop cart.<br>\n";}
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Unable to update the shopping cart for '.$name.'. You may need admin assitance.<br>\n");</script>';
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```